# In Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Studio, the Android option in the target platform is disabled even when SDKs were installed

Tags: android, macos, sdk, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have downloaded and installed several android SDKs on my mac. I can use these SDKs when I code in Android studio, but when trying to build cross-platform apps through Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Studio, the Android option under Target Platforms is disabled.

I have done my research and I have not found any posted solutions that fixed my problem. Has anyone encountered this issue as well? What was your fix?

Comment: Do you have `Xamarin.Android` installed? And do you have VS4M's `Preferences`/`Projects`/`SDK Locations`/`Android`/`Locations` pointing to your `android-sdk-macosx` directory?

Comment: Yes. It was already installed previously. I ended up reinstalling the Xamarin components. It works fine now.